# What is the right way™ to use React setState to show a loading spinner while awaiting an API call with ES7 syntax?

Tags: reactjs

I have gone through a few iterations of setting the state, but I'm not sure which one is right (or works the way I think it should). I want to show a spinner while this.state.loading is true.

```
a = async () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  await someService.doTheThing().then(() => {
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }
}

b = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true}, async () => {
    await someService.doTheThing()
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }
}

c = async () => {
  try {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    await someService.doTheThing()
  } finally {
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }
}
```

It seems like `c` is the right way, but it doesn't seem to work right in my app. I can put a `debugger` right after the setState method and I see the spinner appear, but if the debugger isn't there... the spinner doesn't appear. I originally thought it was a timing thing (API call finishing too fast) but even when I slow down the network with the chrome devtools, it still doesn't show unless I'm debugging.

I could be misunderstanding how this stuff works so please don't assume I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I like `b` for the sole reason you're putting the work in the `setState` callback, you're guaranteed to get the spinner in this case before the async stuff starts happening.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree but I can't seem to get this solution to show my spinner. When I throw a debugger in the callback it shows... but disappears without it. Strange.